# How can I change the height of the header in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, mobile

Im making a mobile webpage but I think the header is too small, height-wise.
Is there any way for me to change it?

Comment: adjusting the height of the header via css inside a mediaquery is a valid option?

Comment: You mean via the jQuery Mobile stylesheet?

Comment: yes, or any other stylesheet you have later on cascade

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a header that doesn't follow the default configuration, simply wrap your custom styled markup in any container, such as div. The plugin won't apply the automatic button logic to the wrapped content inside the header container so you can write custom styles for laying out the content in your header.

It's also possible to create custom bars without using the header data-role at all. For example, start with any container and add the ui-bar class to apply standard bar padding and add the ui-bar-b class to assign the bar swatch styles from your theme. (The "b" can be any swatch letter.) [link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html)

Comment: Ah ok thank you. I actually solved it by just putting in <br /> tags in the header. Maybe not very "legit" but anyway. ^^